# Ubuntu 22.04.3 Installer Does Not Recognize anything at "Installation Type" Menu and crashes when pressing +, -, or change

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have downloaded the official 22.04.3 installer from Ubuntu, and followed their tutorial to making an installation media with Rufus. Everything works very smoothly within Ubuntu when I try it, but when I go through the installation menu, I get stuck on installation type. It shows a blank box, and when I press the +, -, or Change... buttons, it crashes. The "New Partition Table..." and "Revert" buttons are greyed out and not able to be pressed. The only option for "Device for boot loader installation:" is "/dev/sda". When I press "Install now", it gives me an error message saying "No root file system. No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu."

Other information that might help is that I have a Windows 10 installation on this system as well. From what I understand, Ubuntu should give me a menu where I can choose to install alongside Windows, overwrite, etc. I do not even get a menu with that option. It does not recognize Windows. Also, my Windows 10 installation is a legacy mode boot, which might be an issue but I am not sure. I would be very grateful for help on this, and can provide other information as needed.